# Layover in Hongkong

Tags: indian-citizens, layovers, hong-kong

I am going to Berlin and I have a 10 hours layover in Hongkong.I am having an Indian passport. Can I get a visiting visa and go around Hongkong? How much or what all procedure should I go through to get a visiting visa?
Is it possible or advisable to visit the city and come back within 10 hours?

Comment: Of course you can get a visa. But you should use official sources of information, not random people on the internet, to find out how to do that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - but - 9 out of 10 questions on this site are identical such visa questions??  I don't get it?

Comment: @roshualine - 10 hours is perfect to run in to HK and look around.  If your visa issue works out and you can do it, have a ball.